# how to prompt for password in TortoiseHg when pulling from bitbucket

Tags: repository, tortoisehg, bitbucket

I am using BitBucket as a private repository for my project.

When i clone or push change sets into the repository i am prompt for password (i enter the password and everything works fine).

The problem is when i am trying to pull changes.
I am not asked for password and i get the following response in the workbench console.

```
‫% hg --repository local_repository_path fetch --verbose https://username@bitbucket.org/project

fetch
[command returned code 255 Sat Dec 31 18:19:42 2011]
```

if i go to the local repository in cmd and type "hg pull" i do get prompt for password and the pull succeeds.

can anyone please explain to me how to make this work from the workbench.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the section "Overcoming Initial Problems in Pulling and Pushing" of "[My Experience Migrating to TortoiseHg 2.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2011/03/04/my-experience-migrating-to-tortoisehg-2-0.aspx)" from [Saveen Reddy](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/saveen%20reddy/) (also [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468604/saveenr)) can help:

[image: error on pull]

It suggests to unchecked "Remove authentication data from url"

[image: uncheck authentication data]

And it shows how to change the security settings by specifying your username as xxx@gmail.com and entering your password:

[image: security settings]

Comment: it was a good try but it still doesn't help. i am still getting the same.
% hg --repository project_dir fetch --verbose https://project@bitbucket.org/project/project
fetch
[command returned code 255 Sun Jan 01 19:00:28 2012]